# upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 66.38.32.24, server: xxxx.com, request:

Tags: php, nginx

My server is frequently having Timed Out problem, I have adjust parameters such as `fastcg_read_timeout` and `proxy_read_timeout` but it did not solve my problem. Find below my xxxx.conf

```
server {
server_name www.xxxx.com;
return 301 $scheme://xxxx.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    ## Your website name goes here.
    server_name xxxx.com;

    ## Your only path reference.
    root /var/www/xxxx.com;


 # This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
    index index.html index.php;

    error_log    /var/log/nginx/xxxx.com-error.log;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/xxxx.com-access.log;


    # Body size (max upload)
    #    client_max_body_size 64m;
    #    client_body_buffer_size 2m;



    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }
 location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
    # Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    # Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
    # Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite network
    # Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            # This to stop connection timeout
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
           # Time-out Settings
            proxy_send_timeout   150;
            proxy_read_timeout   150;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-sock;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }


    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue while developing on my local nginx machine.

After some extensive research I found a solution to my problem (Unfortunately I cannot find the article anymore).

You could try changing this:

```
fastcgi_pass_unix: localhost:9000;
```

Then run a 'sudo service nginx reload'.

This fixed the issue for me. Hopefully It will too for you.

Comment: you mean    ' fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;' did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem resolved for me. I commented on the proxy_send_timeout and proxy_read_timeout and fastcgi_read_timeout but leave proxy_http_version and proxy_set_header in the codes below.

```
 location / {

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";

      #  proxy_send_timeout   150;
      #  proxy_read_timeout   150;
}
```